# Is there a way to know the user's current state at Firebase sign-in flow?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I wanna know if user is entering email or entering password. Is there a way to know this?

Comment: what's your intention? if you are using edittext, then a ontextchangelistener might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, one may be using an `onClickListener` on the `editText` field of your choice and then using a flag to know like this:

```java
password.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                flag = 1;
                if(flag==1)
                 Log.i("read", "user is entering password");

            }
        });
```

Or you can simple use `onTextChangeListener()` like this:

```java
password.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                flag=0;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                flag=1;
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                flag=2;
            }
        });

        //Now you can track flag according to its value to know what is user doing with the password field
```

Comment: Sorry, not working. I can do it normally like your way, but in FirebaseUI not working.

Comment: FirebaseUI does not allow such things to happen, you should definitely try it the other way around.

Comment: @NoN do mark the answer as correct and upvote it, this helps Stack Overflow future readers and I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Firebase Auth pre-defined UI ([FirebaseUI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui)), you are unable to access the events.  As you can see in the docs, you cannot access / modify much on it.

If you are implementing Firebase Auth the '[hard way](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth)' where you customize the Sign-in UI yourself (for e.g. editText), then you will have more customization and able to detect the events of the UI elements.  Assuming the editText for *username* is `username`.

```
username.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The User is Entering Username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
    }
});
```

The reason why using `onFocus()` instead of other events is this move is simple and does not consume much memory, so you can achieve what you want without heavily invests on the resources which might affect your app performance.

Comment: Sorry, not working. I am trying it on FirebaseUI as you mentioned.

Comment: FirebaseUI doesn't allow you to access the events, at most, you can only know the user is at the sign-in fragment.  Probably you have to give up the implementation of the FirebaseUI,

Answer (score 0):

this is main page -

```
    private FirebaseUser current_state;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

onCreate{
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getinstance();
}

 onStart - method - {
    currentState = mAuth.getCurrentUser()

 if(currentState == null){
 intent it to sign in page;
}
```

}

i hope this will help.